# DELETE multiple rows using IN condition mysqli

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I query a database and save the results into an array. I want to delete rows from database that match the results in said array. I also have to drop a few tables that also share same name as the values stored in the array. Which is why I'm doing a SELECT statement first and not just DELETE

```
    ... //$returnedEventIDs is the results of a SELECT query 

// create array to save events
    $eventsArrayOfIDs = array(); 

//loop through the results and save each to the array
     while ($eventID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($returnedEventIDs)){
          $eventsArrayOfIDs[] = $eventID['EventID'];

      }

       $events = join(',',$eventsArrayOfIDs); 

       $deleteOutdatedEventsAndTables = "DELETE FROM TMVUKMeetUps WHERE EventID IN ($events)";
```

I was hoping that "DELETE FROM table WHERE param IN ($events)"; would delete all rows from table where param  = one of the elements in the $events array.

instead i get error

//ID9nfm9528 is the first element in the array

> Unknown column 'ID9nfm9528' in 'where clause'

How can I update the DELETE statement to achieve my aims?

many thanks

Comment: var_dump $deleteOutdatedEventsAndTables you should find your error for delete

Comment: that gives string(55) "DELETE FROM TMVUKMeetUps WHERE EventID IN (ID9nfm9528);"

Comment: please first check database structure for column EventID. if this field is char/varchar then you need to change this line $events = join(',',$eventsArrayOfIDs);  to : $sap = '';
$events='';

foreach($eventsArrayOfIDs as $id){ 
 $events .=$sap."'$id'";
 $sap = ', '; 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check your database structure for EventID field. if char/varchar type then change `$events = join(',',$eventsArrayOfIDs);` with

```
$sap = '';
$events='';

foreach($eventsArrayOfIDs as $id){  
    $events .=$sap."'$id'";
    $sap = ', ';    
}
```

if it is int type please check the table values manualy by phpmyadmin and fix the data/find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

The query probably has the word **ID9nfm9528** without quotes, that's why mysql assumes that it is a field instead of a string. Remember that you can use database fields in your where clause, and the field are commonly writing as simple strings **(wihtout quotes)**.

Comment: when i var_dump the array is says it is a string though.  array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "ID9nfm9528" }

Comment: Try creating the query dinamycally by appending each array element with quotes.